# Show that if $a\neq b$, $p^a \mid\mid M$ and $p^b \mid\mid N$, then $p^{\min\{a,b\}}\mid\mid M+N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p^a \mid\mid N$ mean that $p^a$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $N$.

Show that if $a \neq b$, $p^a\mid\mid N$ and $p^b \mid\mid M$, then $p^{\min\{a+b\}}\mid\mid M+N$.

Since $p^a \mid\mid M$ we know that $M=p^a Q$ where $(p^a,Q)=1$.  Similarly, $N=p^bP$ where $(P,p^b)=1$.  Without loss of generality assume $a < b$.  Then $$M+N=p^aQ+p^bP=p^a(Q+p^{b-a}P).$$

I'm stuck trying to move forward from the point.  I believe the above shows that $p^a \mid M+N$, but I'm not sure how to show that $p^{a+1}\not\mid M+N$.  How do I show that $a$ is the largest such power.

Answer (score 1):

You mean $\min\{a,b\}$. Saying that $p^a\lVert M$ amounts to saying $M=p^a q$ with $(p,q)=1$ (why?). Thus, write $N=p^a q$ and $M=p^b r$ with $(p,q)=(p,r)=1$. Suppose $a<b$, say $a+k=b$. Then $$M+N=p^a(p^kr+q)$$ Can your show $(p^kr+q,p)=1$?

Comment: I'm not sure why $(p,q)=1$.  I just assumed it was because $p$ is a prime.

Comment: Is it because if $(p,q)=d$, then $d\mid p$ and $d\mid q$.  But since $p$ is prime, then $d=1$ or $d=p$.  If $d=p$, then $p^k=q$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  I'm kind of stuck seeing why this is bad.

Comment: @EugeneTooms For a prime $p$, $(p,a)>1\implies p\mid a$. In particular, if $M=p^kr$ but $(r,p)>1$, $r=pu$, so $M=p^{k+1}u$. This contradicts that $k$ was the greatest number for which $p^k\mid M$.

Comment: $(p^kr+q,p)=1$ because $p \not\mid q$.  Why does that last observation show that $p^a\mid\mid M+N$.

Comment: Because $p^k\lVert M+N$ iff we can write $M+N=p^ku$ with $(u,p)=1$. Since we accomplished this, we're done.